# Autocomplete in F# 2008

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Is there a way to get autocomplete in F# with Visual Studio 2008? That is, true auto completion (suggest words as soon as you start typing), not the kind where you have to manually press a key combination?

Or, if not, since it does work in Visual C# 2010: is the lack of it because it's something C# has and F# doesn't, or because it's something Visual Studio 2010 has and 2008 doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a C#/F# difference.  The F# autocompletion does not start automatically until after you are 'dotting in' to something.  So for example both C# and F# have similar behavior when typing `Con` after `System.`, but only C# starts suggesting after `Sys`.