# F# compiler order of source files

Tags: f#

As I understand it, when using F#, you have to manually list the source files in dependency order for the compiler's benefit (if there is any way around that, please let me know!)

Listing them on the command line from left to right obviously isn't going to scale. Is there a way to at least make it accept the list of files in a text file, one per line, preferably with the ability to put in blank lines and comments? I've checked the compiler options, and I don't see anything that looks promising.

Comment: Reasons besides the compiler to care about this 'feature' http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but the typical way to compile F# (at least on Windows; dunno about Mono) is via MSBuild; the .fsproj project file puts each file as a separate `<Compile>` item on a separate line.  What build tools are you using?

Comment: Tried the Visual Studio 2008 integration, found it frankly worthless, so I'm seeing if falling back on Komodo Edit and the commandline compiler will make it usable. It's frustrating, F# is a beautiful language and definitely what I want for my current project, but as far as I can see, the botch with inter module references is sufficient to render it unusable for any nontrivial purpose.

Comment: Regarding 'ordering matters', see this post of mine: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/13172/ShowThread.aspx#13172

Comment: Regarding the VS integration, wow, I'm a little astonished, though everyone has their own opinion.  You may want to see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/ff681047.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/ff681044.aspx in case there is useful functionality you're not aware of (the videos are VS2010, but much also applies to 2008).

Comment: BTW, you can use MSBuild even if you opt out of VS.  It's a decent build system and very idiomatic for .NET coding.

Comment: Regarding Visual Studio integration, thanks for the links, what I personally wanted from Visual Studio (aside from the issue of build order) was autocomplete and code formatting; but I can hope for those to be included in a later version of Visual F#.

Comment: Regarding ordering, thanks for the link, you present your case eloquently, but here's an explanation from someone else why the trade-off isn't good for line of business applications: http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2008/05/20/f-compiler-considered-too-linear

Comment: But thanks for the tip on MSBuild - what I'm working on isn't a line of business application, it's a theorem prover, so that might be a good enough solution. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Autocomplete works.  Code formatting in a whitespace-significant language is... impossible?  Non-trivial anyway.

Comment: Right, yes the blog about the limitations of "must be in one code block" can indeed be a severe limitation.  You can often work around it by using interfaces or generics, but yes, this is an unfortunate limitation of the current language, and one that we will almost surely address in a future version.

Comment: Code formatting in a whitespace significant language: true, that's a fair point, and a more than worthwhile trade-off. Autocomplete doesn't work according to the answer you gave here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906047/autocomplete-in-f-2008 The other very useful feature of Visual C# is F2 Rename. Perhaps these latter two might be included in a future Visual F#?

Comment: Having slept on it, I think I understand the distinction between projects that care a lot about the 'must be in one code block' limitation and those that don't, is that the ones that do, need or want a significant object-oriented component -- which my current project actually doesn't, so hopefully I can work around it. I'm glad the limitation is likely to be addressed in a future version of the language.

Comment: Just concluded my last attempt at using the Visual Studio integration on yet another stumbling block, so a request for future versions:  please either allow tabs in F# code, or fix Visual Studio to handle spaces correctly, at least on backspace.

Comment: VS2010 does work correctly on backspace; 2008 doesn't, unfortunately.

Comment: Having worked some more with the Visual Studio integration, it's better than I initially thought. A few things: remap manually triggered completion to one keystroke instead of two; if you clean off the byte order marker from .fs files, Visual Studio will leave them clean; the fsi repl can be placed in a tabbed document for easy access.

Answer (score 22):

About the Visual Studio 2008 integration, you can move up/down source files with a right click and choosing `Move Up`, `Move Down` or use the shortcut `Alt+Up Arrow`, `Alt+Down Arrow` after having selected the file.