# how to get f# scripts to call module func?

Tags: f#

Just trying to structure an F# library.  So far it "appears" that:

- I can only reference the C# library from a .fs source file,
- and .fs source files are not available to .fsx script files.

Are any of these statements are correct?  The examples I read say just use an open, but that only works from a .fs file.

Is there a version of

```
#r "System.Drawing.dll"
```

for script files used via f# interactive (fsi) in the same project?

Also, I find the syntax difference between top level modules and lower modules a little strange.  Top me it's weird that the top level doesn't have an equals.

```
module Utilities

    module et =
```

Why not be consistent and have "module moduleName = " for everything?

Comment: I think im not understanding you correctly, but are you aware that, in VS, file order matters for F#? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908473/f-compiler-order-of-source-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is important to note that "References" in Visual Studio in F# only apply to the current project. If you're working in a script file, it does not see the libraries referenced by the project.

To reference a library in a script file (e.g. `Script.fsx`), you can write (you can use both absolute paths and relative paths):

```
#r @"C:\<path_to_library>\library.dll"
```

If you want to load a file that is not a script (e.g. `Library.fs`) from a script file you can use:

```
#load "Library.fs"
```

The `fs` file itself cannot contain directives like `#r`, so if the file is using some library that needs to be referenced, you need to have an `#r` directive in the main script file (to reference the library before loading the source file).

As for the module inconsistency, the main reason is that when you use `module Foo` or `namespace Foo` at the top-level, you do not need to indent the rest of the file:

```
module Foo

let bar = 10
module Sub = 
  let bar = 12
```

Comment: "you need to have an #r directive in the main script file (to reference the library before loading the source file)" -- that seems a pity.  Do you think they'll aim to harmonise that a bit more, or is it not much of a problem in practice?

Comment: can we point to a .csproj or a .fsproj file instead of the .dll?  Pointing to proj\bin\debug\proj.dll is not as smooth as it could be.  Thanks though.  #load works as expected now.